# Trying to get start time and end time from a list of dates and times (Weekly)

Tags: excel

I have a listing of production date and times and I want to calculate the time window that they were utilized. My list looks something like this but with many more weeks:

```
Action | Date Time Start | Date Time End    | Week Num | Lot Num | Machine Num
Setup  | 9/12/2022  1:00 | 9/12/2022  3:00  | 1        | 12345   | 101            
MFG    | 9/12/2022  3:00 | 9/13/2022 13:00  | 1        | 12345   | 101            
Setup  | 9/13/2022 14:00 | 9/13/2022 15:30  | 1        | 54321   | 101
MFG    | 9/13/2022 15:30 | 9/16/2022 22:00  | 1        | 54321   | 101
```

So what I want to grab from this list is the start Date Time of the week and the End date time of the same week to give me the Total time of 117:00. I don't know the best way of doing this.

Comment: Is this coming from a CSV, where this is a large string being split amongst columns, meaning the data is all `string` format, not date/time?  That would make a difference... I ask because of the format of spacing for the date/time start/end, where it looks like a string with intended spacing.

Comment: Have you looked at all the date and time functions?

Comment: @Cyril This is all in a table in Excel

Comment: @SolarMike I did and none of them will extract the first date time of the week and last date time of the same week (or give me the difference of the two)

Answer (score 0):

So, a quick example as shown:

[image]

But going across midnight will be an issue. Posted a solution to that on here before. Also, another tip is make sure of your formatting.

Comment: This works if I manually do it for every week but what can I do when there are a years works of dates and times and changes (approximately 7000 entries) and I'd like to do this for every week and every piece of machinery